# How to Implement this to mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

With one select command, display all cats with
male sex and dogs whith female sex

i'have tried `select * from pet where species='cat' && sex='m' | species='dog' && sex='f';`

Comment: beware of || deprecation use OR https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html

Answer (score 1):

You connect boolean expressions in SQL using `AND` and `OR`, not strange operators lifted from C:

```
where (species = 'cat' and sex = 'm') or
      (species = 'dog' and sex = 'f');
```

MySQL also supports `IN` with tuples:

```
where (species, sex) in ( ('cat', 'm'), ('dog', 'f') );
```

And just to clarify:  MySQL *does* understand `&&` and `||` as real boolean operators.  I strongly discourage anyone from using this (mostly my general preference for standards when they are equivalent).  However, `&` and `|` are *bitwise* operators, so they may not do what you expect in a boolean context.

Comment: "strange operators lifted from C:" I loved that. hahaha!